# Simple recursion question

Tags: c++, recursion

Let's say we have a simple recursion like.

```
int x(int a){
   if(a<10)
     x(a+1);
    else
      !STOP!
    b++;
return b;
}
```

Globaly:

```
int b=0;
```

In main we could have something like this:

```
  int p=x(1);
```

Is there any way to stop the recursion so that the p will be 0, this means that "b++" will never be executed.

I'll be grateful if you could tell me some expresion to put instead of the !STOP!

But, I don't want anything like this, I just want to stop the recursion, like break; does in a while() loop...:

```
int ok=0;
  int x(int a){
       if(a<10)
         x(a+1);
        else
          ok=1;
      if(ok==0)
        b++;
    return b;
    }
```

If there's anything unclear about the question, just ask.

Comment: Oh, and when I mean stopping the recursion I also mean automaticaly deleting the stack...

Comment: Cristy, you can edit your question rather than adding comments to it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It seems like you might be using the wrong tool for the job, but it's hard to tell without a concrete example of what you plan on doing.

Comment: Is your question about a generic problem?  Ie, what should I put in place of !STOP!?

Comment: I actually asked myself if I can do this a long time ago when I really needed it. Now it's just a generic problem, so I will know in the future if I'll ever need this stuff.

Comment: @Cristy - Here's a quick tip: place the stop-case before the recursive-case in your code.  It might make things clearer.  Most intro books teach recursion that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why wouldn't you do this?

```
int x(int a){
   if(a<10) {
      x(a+1);
      b++;
   }
   return b;
}
```

The thing is, though, you're modifying a global in a recursive routine, which is not especially threadsafe and pretty sloppy.  You're returning a value that is always ignored except by the top level caller.  You're also doing something that is better off being done in a loop (but I assume that your actual case is bigger than this, or you're a student).

You can't really "break" the recursion - returning unwinds well enough.  In oldey-timey C you might use setjmp/longjmp (and all its perils - in other words, DON'T), and in C++ you might use try/catch/throw, which will unwind the stack as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answear!  
So the ideea is that I can't "break" a recursion...
Anyway, the ideea to do this was to stop the program from useless calculations...
I mean, I could have a recursion that was needed to go all the way forward, and then, when coming back to stop half-way the recursion, without "recursing" through the remaining half. I can't explain too good, but I hope you get what I'm saying :D

Comment: As plinth say, you could throw an exception in this case.

Comment: I never used throw&catch and I've been programming alot in the past 2 years. I mean I should really read about it. :)

Comment: Although you *could* use an exception here, you really *shouldn't*. Exceptions should be for *exceptional* (i.e. rare, unexpected) situations. They should not be used for flow control.

Comment: I think bailing out of a recursive call stack is an ideal use for an exception.

Comment: @Tyler: Exceptions will also be a very slow way to do flow control. I once took some code that had an exception for flow control in a tight inner loop, refactored it and made it hugely faster.

Answer (score 1):

How about like this?

```
int x(int a){
   if(a>0 && a<10)
     x(a+1);
   b++;
   return b;
}
```

Comment: This code will just execute b++; for 1 time if I call the function as x(1). Because 1<0 && 1<10 will be false. This just stops the function from entering the recursion, it doesn't stop the recursion to "go back" once it started...

Comment: @Jerry sorry, about that, fixed my typo.

Answer (score 1):

How about returning?

```
int x(int a){
   if(a<10)
     x(a+1);
    else
      return b;
    b++;
return b;
}
```

I think this looks a bit better

```
int x(int a){
   if(a<10)
     x(a+1);
    else
      return b;

    return ++b;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I think You could use exception mechanism to unwind the stack and get to the point of first invocation, but it's safe after entering `main()`. Referencing `b` in `x`, given the code:

```
int b = 0;
int p = x(1);
```

suggests that `x` is used for initialization of some global variable and may be executed before `main()`. How about using some helper function that wraps invocation of `x` in a try - catch block and throwing an exception in the place of |STOP|?

Comment: The idea, I believe, is to be able to cancel the whole calculation, discard intermediate results, and abort all further processing.  `return` just stops the calculation from continuing with more recursion.

Comment: If I'll use return it will just stop the current call of the function to continue and will go back and continue the recursion... I mean, when I say !STOP! I really mean stop :D. (totally exit the function with no future calls from the recursion,clear the stack...)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing in C++ that will unwind the stack like that is an exception.  There's also `setjmp()/longjmp()`, but those should never be used in a C++ program.  Any other construct can at most return from the current function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to declare `b` in `main()`, and use `b` in `x()` then there's something wrong already to begin with. Instead, make `b` into a local variable by passing it as a parameter to `x`, and returning a modified version of `b`.

```
int x(int a, int b){
   if(a<10)
      return x(a+1,b+1);
    else
      return b;
}
```

Comment: That is just a fast example I've created. I've put that b++; in the function to show that there would be some code after the recursion-call inside the function that I'll don't want be executed... :)

Comment: You can also remove the else since it's redundant, once the program returns it will never run the code below.

Comment: @ChikSentMeHighE: don't nitpick :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of using an Exception for control.  I don't expect you'll save many cycles by using Exceptions instead of if/return statements.  You're going to have to test your boundary conditions anyway before throwing an Exception.

You can however simplify the problem a bit by changing the return type of the function.

```
bool x(int a){
  if(ok) //Exit early before next call up?
    return true;  
  if(a<10){
    if(x(a+1))  //Have we been told to exit early?
      return true; //Yes
    b++; //Do some work
    if(ok) //Exit early in the next call down?
      return true;  
  }
  return false; //Normal Exit
}
```

Comment: That's a little messy, and still doesn't "stop" the recursion :D...
Thanks for help anyway :).

Comment: Could you explain how this doesn't "stop" the recursion?